# I have this when am using django with mongoDB, DatabaseError at /foods/41007428/65bffaaab212b521886f0e47/ No exception message supplied

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, pymongo

**Here is the error that am getting when I try to retrieve data**

DatabaseError at /foods/41007428/65bffaaab212b521886f0e47/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/foods/41007428/65bffaaab212b521886f0e47/
Django Version: 4.1.13
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Location: C:\Users\omuya\projects\food_backend\foodenv\Lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py, line 59, in execute
Raised during:  foods.views.foodByCategoryandCode
Python Executable:  C:\Users\omuya\projects\food_backend\foodenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.1
Python Path:
['C:\Users\omuya\projects\food_backend\food_api_project',
'C:\Users\omuya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.zip',
'C:\Users\omuya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\DLLs',
'C:\Users\omuya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib',
'C:\Users\omuya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312',
'C:\Users\omuya\projects\food_backend\foodenv',
'C:\Users\omuya\projects\food_backend\foodenv\Lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 05 Feb 2024 23:09:11 +0000

The above exception ( Keyword: None Sub SQL: None FAILED SQL: ('SELECT "foods_product"."_id", "foods_product"."title", "foods_product"."foodTags", "foods_product"."foodType", "foods_product"."code", "foods_product"."isAvailable", "foods_product"."restaurant_id", "foods_product"."rating", "foods_product"."ratingCount", "foods_product"."description", "foods_product"."price", "foods_product"."additives", "foods_product"."imageUrl", "foods_product"."category_id", "foods_product"."time", "foods_product"."created_at", "foods_product"."updated_at" FROM "foods_product" WHERE ("foods_product"."category_id" = %(0)s AND "foods_product"."code" = %(1)s AND "foods_product"."isAvailable")',) Params: (('65bffaaab212b521886f0e47', '41007428'),) Version: 1.3.6) was the direct cause of the following exception:

I just wanted to get filtered according to code and category

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def foodByCategoryandCode(request,catid,code):
    foods = Product.objects.filter(category__pk = catid, code = code,isAvailable = True)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(foods, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**This my url for retrieving the data**

`path('foods/<str:code>/<str:catid>/', foodByCategoryandCode, name='random-by-code-and-category'),`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False,max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    foodTags = models.JSONField(default = [])
    foodType = models.JSONField(default = [])
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    isAvailable = models.BooleanField()
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1,validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    ratingCount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    additives = models.JSONField(default = [])
    imageUrl = models.JSONField(default = [])
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self._id:
            self._id = str(ObjectId())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this in my views and it worked but don't if was the correct approach, since the problem was filtering by `bool` `=` `isAvailable`

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def foodByCategoryAndCode(request,catid,code):
    foods = Product.objects.filter(Q(code=code, category=catid))
    _foods = [food for food in foods if food.isAvailable == True]
    serializer = ProductSerializer(_foods, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```